# Log Apollo iOS Client GraphQL query variables and url to console?

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, apollo

I would like to print the url of my Apollo iOS Client GraphQL queries to the Xcode console when the query is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [Apollo iOS Client docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/initialization/#setting-up-apollointerceptor-chains-with-interceptorprovider), a logging interceptor can be added in a custom Interceptor Provider.

I created a custom interceptor provider using the code from DefaultInterceptorProvider, and included the logging interceptor.

```
import Apollo    

class InterceptorProviderWithLogging: InterceptorProvider {

  private let client: URLSessionClient
  private let store: ApolloStore
  private let shouldInvalidateClientOnDeinit: Bool

  public init(client: URLSessionClient = URLSessionClient(),
          shouldInvalidateClientOnDeinit: Bool = true,
          store: ApolloStore) {
    self.client = client
    self.shouldInvalidateClientOnDeinit = shouldInvalidateClientOnDeinit
    self.store = store
  }

  deinit {
    if self.shouldInvalidateClientOnDeinit {
      self.client.invalidate()
    }
  }

  open func interceptors<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(for operation: Operation) -> [ApolloInterceptor] {
    return [
      MaxRetryInterceptor(),
      CacheReadInterceptor(store: self.store),
      RequestLoggingInterceptor(),        // added logging interceptor
      NetworkFetchInterceptor(client: self.client),
      ResponseCodeInterceptor(),
      JSONResponseParsingInterceptor(cacheKeyForObject: self.store.cacheKeyForObject),
      AutomaticPersistedQueryInterceptor(),
      CacheWriteInterceptor(store: self.store),
    ]
  }

  open func additionalErrorInterceptor<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(for operation: Operation) -> ApolloErrorInterceptor? {
    return nil
  }
}

class RequestLoggingInterceptor: ApolloInterceptor {

  func interceptAsync<Operation: GraphQLOperation>(
    chain: RequestChain,
    request: HTTPRequest<Operation>,
    response: HTTPResponse<Operation>?,
    completion: @escaping (Result<GraphQLResult<Operation.Data>, Error>) -> Void) {
                
    if let url = try? request.toURLRequest().url?.absoluteString.removingPercentEncoding {
        if let variables = request.operation.variables {
            print("\(request.operation.operationName) parameters: \(variables) \(url)")
        } else {
            print("\(request.operation.operationName) \(url)")
        }
    }
    
    chain.proceedAsync(request: request, response: response, completion: completion)
  }
}
```

I use the custom interceptor provider in the Request Chain Network Transport.

```
private(set) lazy var apolloClient: ApolloClient = {

  let store = ApolloStore()
  let interceptorProvider = InterceptorProviderWithLogging(store: store)

  let requestChainTransport = RequestChainNetworkTransport(
    interceptorProvider: interceptorProvider,
    endpointURL: url,
    additionalHeaders: [:],
    autoPersistQueries: false,
    requestBodyCreator: ApolloRequestBodyCreator(),
    useGETForQueries: true,
    useGETForPersistedQueryRetry: false
  )

  return ApolloClient(networkTransport: requestChainTransport, store: store)
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending GraphQLQuery provides access to the operation name, operation id, and variables, which can be used to build up the url.  I also print out the operation name and variables for the query.

```
extension GraphQLQuery {

    func printInfo() {
    
        if let variables = self.variables?.JSONString {
        
            let cleanedVariables = variables.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
            print("GraphQL Query: \(self.operationName) \(variables))")
        
            if let operationID = self.operationIdentifier {
                            
                let url = "\(GraphQLClient.shared.url)?extensions={\"persistedQuery\":{\"sha256Hash\":\"\(operationID)\",\"version\":1}}&id=\(operationID)&operationName=\(self.operationName)&variables=\(cleanedVariables)"
                print("GraphQL URL", url)
            }
        
        } else {
            print("GraphQL Query: \(self.operationName)")

            if let operationID = self.operationIdentifier {
                            
                let url = "\(GraphQLClient.shared.url)?extensions={\"persistedQuery\":{\"sha256Hash\":\"\(operationID)\",\"version\":1}}&id=\(operationID)&operationName=\(self.operationName)"
                print("GraphQL URL", url)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let standingsQuery = GetStandingsForSportQuery(sportID: sportIDInt, season: season)
standingsQuery.printInfo()
```

Example output:

```
GraphQL Query: getStandingsForSport {"sportID":7,"season":"2020"})
GraphQL URL: https://api.company.com/graphql?extensions={"persistedQuery":{"sha256Hash":"932b414fdadb641f95659d6c61aa29d6d6b0ccf1fa704a0ace751187b90b8cac","version":1}}&id=932b414fdadb641f95659d6c61aa29d6d6b0ccf1fa704a0ace751187b90b8cac&operationName=getStandingsForSport&variables={"sportID":1,"season":"2020"}
```

The url format in this example may not be typical as we're using persisted queries.  I used Charles proxy to see the actual url being sent so I'd know the format.

You could also extend GraphQLOperation instead of GraphQLQuery to get this same info, which would also support mutations and subscriptions.

Comment: There is an easy way to get the QueryName: https://docs.proxyman.io/advanced-features/graphql#2-show-graphql-query-name-on-the-main-table-view

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to write swift code to extract the QueryName.

Use Proxyman, like Charles Proxy. It will display the QueryName on the column by default.

Ref: https://docs.proxyman.io/advanced-features/graphql

[image: GraphQL QueryName with Proxyman]

Comment: This won't work when debugging on real iOS device

Comment: it should work if you've installed Proxyman Certificate on your iOS devices. You can follow this doc at https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/ios-device